# SQL GROUP BY for Thread Inbox

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i am trying to get **last** message of **each** conversation grouped

SenderId(1) ReceiverId(2) and SenderId(2) ReceiverId(1) is from the same thread.

| Id | Body | ts | SenderId | ReceiverId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ghfghfg | 13/7/2022 15:09:35 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | bnmbnm | 14/7/2022 15:11:16 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | ertet | 15/7/2022 15:13:11 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | xcvx | 23/7/2022 14:58:38 | 2 | 1 |

i tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE SenderId = {current_user_id} OR ReceiverId = {current_user_id} 
GROUP BY SenderId, ReceiverId
```

but it is not giving only one per thread and not the last message.

I have tried other long workarounds methods which works but i wanted more direct approach.

Any help will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Can two people have two (or more) different conversations stored inside your db? In that case, how do you distinguish when a conversation ends and a new one starts out?

Comment: No, i would create another column to differentiate.

Comment: bump this question...

Comment: Questions can't get bumped on SO by any means: your comment has the only side effect of notifying people who have written in this comments thread (only me). Please provide a bigger sample of your data, maybe including also side cases where TheImpaler's solution would fail with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` combined with `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(
    partition by least(senderid, receiverid), greatest(senderid, receiverid)
    order by ts desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f091dc51bf2a13795b2ff24a4cb9987).

Comment: the answer does not work if you add other users. eg conversion user id 8

Comment: @digiadit Please add the example in a fiddle.